# TortoiseGit - pre-rebase hook not executed

Tags: git, githooks, tortoisegit

I'm working under Windows 7 and I have installed msysgit and TortoiseGit.
I wrote a pre-rebase hook for a git repository.

The hook is called when I rebase the repo from Git Bash.
However the hook is not called if I start the rebase from TortoiseGit.
I tried to write a pre-commit hook, and it works from bot Git Bash and TortoiseGit.

The hook is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright (c) 2006, 2008 Junio C Hamano
#
# The "pre-rebase" hook is run just before "git rebase" starts doing
# its job, and can prevent the command from running by exiting with
# non-zero status.
#
# The hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- the upstream the series was forked from.
# $2 -- the branch being rebased (or empty when rebasing the current branch).
#
# This sample shows how to prevent topic branches that are already
# merged to 'next' branch from getting rebased, because allowing it
# would result in rebasing already published history.

echo '************************************************************'
echo '********************** Running CMake  **********************'
echo '************************************************************'
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11" -BBuild/ -Hsrc
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see (using `git reflog`), 'rebase' in TortoiseGit does not really perform a true `git rebase`. Instead, TortoiseGit emulates a rebase using cherry-picks.

I don't know why, maybe it is to enable the gui for interactive rebase?

Anyway, since a true rebase is not performed, no rebase-related hook will be run.

Comment: The "true" git also uses cherry-picks ;)

Comment: @MrTux in what sense? Cherry picks and rebases looks different in `git reflog` and triggers different hooks.

Comment: Rebase is just a bash-script around cherry-pick.